# SSAS -> MDX -> How to create a query that returns a topcount by a date period i.e. week?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

I have received a recent request to create a query that returns the top 100 customers by revenue per week.  I can obviously and easily return the top 100 customers as a whole but when I add in the week attribute, my query times out.  I was just wondering if some out there has run into this or has been able to produce a comparable query?

My query that works without week present. :

```
     SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Revenue] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY TopCount ( { ([Customer].[Customer Id].[Customer Id].ALLMEMBERS * [Customer].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS  ) }, 100, [Measures].[Revenue])  ON ROWS 
FROM [DW]
```

My query with week present that just times out everything completely. :

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Revenue] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY TopCount ( { ([Customer].[Customer Id].[Customer Id].ALLMEMBERS * [Customer].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Date Link].[Week].[Week].ALLMEMBERS ) }, 100, [Measures].[Revenue])  ON ROWS 
FROM [DW]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this give you the top 100 customers and the week they were top in? So customer A could be in 1st position in week one, 5th position in week two, and so on, but you'd get 100 rows in total not 100 per week?

Try something like

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Revenue] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{
[Date Link].[Week].[Week].ALLMEMBERS *
{
TopCount ( { ([Customer].[Customer Id].[Customer Id].ALLMEMBERS * [Customer].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS ) }, 100, [Measures].[Revenue])  
}
}
ON ROWS 
FROM [DW]
```

I think you may need to use GENERATE instead of * with the week members, can't remember and trying to do this off the top of my head ;)

Comment: Marking as answer as this is the closest I have got to one.  This is providing me with results but not 100 customers a week.  It is showing 90 some weeks and 70 on another, I will research using the generate function for this.  Thanks as this will give me some more direction.

Comment: @UserSmith have you checked those weeks, and are you 100% sure there are at least 100 customers with measures.revenue for that week alone?

Comment: Yes, I checked this to make sure via sql.  That was my first guess also.  I am going to check later as I believe someone is updating data and it could be giving me mixed results.  Again thanks for your direction on this.

Comment: Rechecked after updating went through the issue was that with this test data I am reviewing did not have 100 customers present.....good call.